# Faster Arrays sort function in java

Tags: java

I found this code snippet on codeforces.

```
 public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
        a = shuffle(a, new SplittableRandom());
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return a;
    }
```

Is this a better way to sort an array rather than using just `Arrays.sort(a)`. Why or Why not?

Comment: Better to define better first...

Comment: How could something shuffling an array randomly and then sorting it be faster or better than just sorting it?

Comment: @lexicore sure, that's my point. But the OP doesn't ask if **there** is a better way. The question is: *is **this** a better way*.

Comment: Are you asking if "shuffle-then-`Arrays.sort`" is "better" that simply `Arrays.sort`? Or if there's anything "better" than `Arrays.sort`? (Whatever "better" means.)

Comment: @JBNizet On a second thought, it seems to me the question is not as trivial as it seems. `Arrays.sort` uses `DualPivotQuicksort` which (I think) is not randomized. So shuffling the array might even make some sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645471/how-does-random-shuffling-in-quick-sort-help-in-increasing-the-efficiency-of-the

Answer (score 0):

It's because Arrays.sort() uses Quicksort (Dual-Pivot Quicksort, to be more precise), which can have a complexity of O(n^2) (worst case complexity), instead of O(n log(n)), when the array has small or big values on the first/last position. In other words, Quicksort has the best efficiency when the order of the elements is completely random.

You can find a more detailed explanation  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645471/how-does-random-shuffling-in-quick-sort-help-in-increasing-the-efficiency-of-the).

Comment: This actually seems to be a duplicate.